# Find and replace empty spaces on Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

When I convert an Excel doc with tables to XML or aixml (Adobe Illustrator XML), if the tables have empty cells, this gives me an error. I want to know how can I locate and remove these spaces like in the below example:

```
<S>
      <p>4</p>
    </S>
   (this empty space should be deleted)
   (this empty space should be deleted)
   (this empty space should be deleted)
  </v:sampleDataSet>
  <v:sampleDataSet dataSetName="DP01E.100.002">
    <Referencia>
      <p>DP01E.100.002</p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't understand the question. If it's not only me, please consider rephrasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to remove all lines that are empty or have only spaces. If so, in Notepad++, go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   ^\s*^
   ```
2. Replace with:

   ```
   leave empty
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press "Replace All"