# How to format list items using notepad++

Tags: list, format, notepad++

I have a loooong list of list items that I have to format. Is there a way to do a replace all and format this:

```
    <li>
    aragonese</li>

    <li>
    sidamo</li>

    <li>
    altaic_languages</li>

    <li>
    luo</li>

    <li>
    papuan_languages</li>

    <li>
    khotanese</li>

    <li>
    kinyarwanda</li>

    <li>
    elamite</li>
```

To this?

```
<li>German</li>
<li>sidamo</li>
<li>altaic_languages</li>
```

Comment: are you looking for a programming way to do this?  Otherwise, can you  use search and replace?

Comment: No, not a programming way. I want to search and replace but using replace "\n" to empty does not seem to work. And how can I get the <li> above to appear right next to for example german? LIke <li>german.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions primarily.  Please check  take the [tour] and read our [ask] page - Perhaps you can ask your question at https://superuser.com instead?

Comment: I only asked it because I have seen other questions such as this answered on StackOverFlow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500279/find-and-replace-empty-spaces-on-notepad Thank you anyway.

Comment: Fair enough; with so many questions, some do slip by. Did you try search and replace with regex then? (i.e. regular expression) and use `\n` ?

Comment: As long as all of the lines are formatted similarly to begin with, this is the type of thing I would use a macro for if I couldn't get search and replace to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `li>\R\h*`
- Replace with: `li>`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
li>         # literally
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Wow that's amazing! I knew it was possible, thank you.

Comment: @AlexMartinez: You're welcome, glad it helps.